# Can a WCF Service display a help page or other content?

Tags: wcf

If you enter a service endpoint in a browser you get a Microsoft generated page with a link to the wsdl and some sample C# and VB code for creating an instance of the service client.  If you enter the wsdl link in a browser you get the wsdl. This all assumes no strange security restrictions of course.

Is there a way to have a service return a page of your own design? If I wanted to have a nice help screen describing the available service methods, or describing possible error messages for example. Either replacing the MS generated default page, or something that can be viewed like a wsdl but with a ?help query parameter for example.

I'm looking for really simple here with minimal changes to the existing services. If possible something that can be done by content creators or technical writers and not the service developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can override the default help page, but you can definitely serve up a help page.  This article on [WCF Custom Help Page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Help-Page-6f5a90f0) explains how.

Comment: This didn't answer my specific needs, but it led me down the right path. Thanks. I had to tweak things a little to get it to work for a non-REST WCF service, but I was able to get it to serve up fairly simple pages which is what I needed.